# Yii2 conditional join on two foreign keys to same table

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have two tables in the database, namely "user" and "user_user" which links users to users (many to many)

in user_user there are two columns "user_id_0" and "user_id_1"

I need to get all users where the current logged in user id is equal to either
user_id_0 OR user_id_1.

I can achieve this simply with sql:

```sql
select * from user u
    inner join user_user uu 
    on uu. user_id_0 = u.id
       or uu.user_id_1 = u.id
    [where u.id = 1]
```

In Yii2 I'm stuck with something like this:

($this would be of type User)

```
$this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id_0'])
        ->viaTable('user_user', ['user_id_0' => 'id'],
           function($query) {
              $query->orOnCondition(['user_id_1' => 'id']);
         });
```

Now this can't work as hasMany() links to only one foreign key. How do I do something like the SQL above? To join two foreign keys with 'or'.

I this possible or would you suggest a different database design? The goal here is really to enable users have "friends" or "connections" to other users like you would in a social network.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data

Comment: What does this sql query do? Is it for MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this works as you expect. I didn't try it out.

IMO the query should look like this (assuming MySQL):

```
SET @id = 1; // or whatever

SELECT     user.*
FROM       user
INNER JOIN user_user
ON         user.id = user_user.id1 OR user.id = user_user.id2
WHERE      user.id != @id AND (user_user.id1 = @id OR user_user.id2 = @id)
GROUP BY   user.id;
```

This could be realized in class User like this:

```
public function getConnectedPersons() {

    return self::find()
        ->select('user.*')
        ->innerJoin('user_user', ['or',
                'user.id=user_user.user_id_0',
                'user.id=user_user.user_id_1'
            ]
        )->where(['and',
                ['user.id' => $this->id],
                ['or',
                    ['user_user.user_id_0' => $this->id],
                    ['user_user.user_id_1' => $this->id]
                ]
            ]
        )->groupBy('user.id');
}
```

This returns an ActiveQuery object. Append `->all()` if you want to get the user array directly.

I hope this works. It is untested. But you may get the idea and give me feedback if anything is wrong.

This might not be the best solution. It doesn't use viaTable() which should also work somehow.